# Should I have normal methods in controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So basically I have a view model that looks like this:

```
public class KorisnikDugovanjaViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Dug> Dugovanja { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Korisnik> Korisnici { get; set; }
        public Korisnik Korisnik { get; set; }

        public decimal UkupnoDuznik { get; set; }
        public decimal UkupnoVjerovnik { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SumaPoDuzniku> SumePoDuzniku { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SumaPoVjerovniku> SumePoVjerovniku { get; set; }
    }

    public class SumaPoDuzniku
    {
        public string Ime { get; set; }
        public decimal Iznos { get; set; }
    }

    public class SumaPoVjerovniku
    {
        public string Ime { get; set; }
        public decimal Iznos { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to pass that model to my view in 2 scenarios, on the index page, and when i POST to the index page, so should i populate that model in both my index metod and my http post index method, or should i make a method that looks like this and just call it when i need to pass the model?

```
public KorisnikDugovanjaViewModel VratiModel()
        {
            int userId = int.Parse(Session["User"].ToString());

            KorisnikDugovanjaViewModel model = new KorisnikDugovanjaViewModel
            {
                Dugovanja = dugRepository.Dugovanja
                    .Where(m => (m.Duznik.Id == userId || m.Vjerovnik.Id == userId)),

                Korisnici = korisnikRepository.Korisnici,

                Korisnik = korisnikRepository.Korisnici.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == userId),

                UkupnoDuznik = dugRepository.Dugovanja
                    .Where(m => m.DuznikId == userId && !m.Zatvoreno).Sum(m => m.Iznos),

                UkupnoVjerovnik = dugRepository.Dugovanja
                    .Where(m => m.VjerovnikId == userId && !m.Zatvoreno).Sum(m => m.Iznos),

                SumePoDuzniku = dugRepository.Dugovanja
                    .Where(a => a.DuznikId == userId && !a.Zatvoreno)
                    .GroupBy(a => a.Vjerovnik.Ime)
                    .Select(a => new SumaPoDuzniku
                    {
                        Ime = a.Key,
                        Iznos = a.Sum(b => b.Iznos)
                    }),

                SumePoVjerovniku = dugRepository.Dugovanja
                    .Where(a => a.VjerovnikId == userId && !a.Zatvoreno)
                    .GroupBy(a => a.Duznik.Ime)
                    .Select(a => new SumaPoVjerovniku
                    {
                        Ime = a.Key,
                        Iznos = a.Sum(b => b.Iznos)
                    })
            };

            return model;
        }
```

Or is it usually done in an entirely different way? I just want to learn how to structure my code efficiently.
Also I noticed that when i POST with a form, the page refreshes, the `VratiModel()` method should return a view populated with new model, but it isn't, the model stays the same until i refresh the page again, is that normal? Should I use model state somehow? I'm clueless.

Bonus question: How do i handle sessions? Should I check whether user is logged in in the beginning of every method? Could it be done in the constructor? How does the constructor of the controller actually work? You may have noticed that i use my `userId` on the beginning of the `VratiModel()` method, and on all the other methods, it just seems kind of bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it's perfectly okay to have non-action methods in your controller. However, you should note that technically any *public* method can be an action. As a result, your non-action methods should be either protected or private, depending on whether you need them to be available to derived classes or not.

As to your view model not updating on post, it's difficult to say without being able to see your actions. However, generally speaking, you'd have something like:

```
public ActionResult Foo()

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(FooViewModel model)
```

In other words, the post action would accept the view model back as a param. If that's the scenario with your code, then your method that returns your view model, should optionally accept the posted version.

```
protected KorisnikDugovanjaViewModel VratiModel(KorisnikDugovanjaViewModel model = null)
```

Then, if the model is null, you create a new one. Otherwise, you simply alter the posted version.

Finally, it looks as though you're using some custom method for authentication/authorization. That's generally a bad idea, anyways, but it kind of makes it impossible to really help you with your bonus question, since we don't have visibility into how all that works. However, if you use an out of the box solution, like Identity, things are pretty easy.

To ensure that an action is protected, such that a user needs to be logged in to access it, you'd just decorate your action/controller with `[Authorize]`. If you do it at the controller level, then all actions will be authorized by default.

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : Controller
```

You then don't need to check anything in your action. The user will automatically either be served the action or redirected to the login page to authorize themselves.

If you do need some sort of information about the user, you can fetch that via `User`. It's a built-in property on the controller. In particular, you can do stuff like `User.Identity.Name` to get the username or `User.Identity.GetUserId()` to get the id for the user. If you need more specific information from the user table in the database, you can then use the user's id to query it.

Comment: Okay I somehow totally forgot that I should declare it as 'private'. That's probably what bugged me. On the model thing, the model binding thing works perfectly, but the scenario is like this: my view page shows a table from my database, I have a form in the view that can update some rows, when i post the form the database is successfully updated, but my view page didn't reflect the change, unless i click 'refresh'. Also, loved you in Guardians of the Galaxy :D

Comment: Make sure you're returning the view *with the post model*, i.e. `return View(model);`.

Comment: I am returning the view with the model from the method in the question, like this: `return View(VratiModel());` after the post method updates the database.  It should generate a new view, but it doesn't, unless i force it by refreshing and not using post. Both the normal action, and the post action have the same line at the end, which is: `return View(VratiModel());` but the post one somehow returns the model with the state it had before I posted.

Comment: Give my answer another read. That's what I was talking about with your `VratiModel` method needing to accept an existing view model instance. You're essentially return a new view model both on GET and POST, so the user's changes are not shown.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand what you are saying, but what is wrong with my approach, that the `VratiModel` method simply reads from the database and returns the view based on that, and since the user's changes to the database are done in the POST before I call the `return View(VratiModel())` why wouldn't it be reflected? Or maybe I just don't understand how entity framework and the repositories work so the mistake is somewhere in there?

Comment: There's likely some disconnect somewhere in the data access layer that's causing the entities to not be updated immediately. Regardless, this wouldn't be a problem if you utilized the post values rather than recreating the view model from scratch.

Comment: Okay thank you, I just wanted to know why, I will use your approach of course.

Comment: Hi just wanted to let you know that I researched a bit, and found that I shouldn't return a view with post, but i should redirect to the get method, so that I don't have to use `modelstate.clear()` which fixes my issue above (not returning updated values), and the user can refresh after and browser won't ask if it should resubmit the post values. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well, yes, and no. Yes, you definitely should employ the PRG pattern (Post-Redirect-Get), but *on success*. If there's a validation error, you *should* return the view directly, to allow the user to correct their mistakes.